# Error al almacenar imagenes al servidor y a BDD PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php7

Estoy trabajando con un pequeño programa que carga 3 imágenes a la carpeta de mi servidor local y a una BDD. Los registros a la BDD se generan exitosamente pero las imágenes no se cargan en la carpeta del servidor y estoy suponiendo que es la forma en que coloco la ruta del $path pero ya he intentado de muchas formas y ninguna me da éxito. (mi carpeta de imágenes esta en la carpeta raíz del proyecto). 
Les dejo mi código:

formulario.php

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="id_registro" value="<?php echo 
   $_GET['id_registro']?> ">
   <label for="archivo">Ingresar imagenes TATUAJES</label>
   <input type="file" class="form-control-file" accept="image/*" 
   id="archivo" name="file_array[]" multiple/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
 </form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];

//ruta de la carpeta
$path = "/imagenes";
$directorio = opendir("$path");

if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){


$name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
$type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
$size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
$error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "img/".$name_array[$i])){

        $act = "INSERT INTO registros (id_registro,imagen1,imagen2,imagen3) 
values ('$id_registro','$name_array[0]','$name_array[1]','$name_array[2]')";
        if($mysqli->query($act)){
          echo "<img src='".$path.$name_array[$i]."'> Las imágenes fueron 
subidas exitosamente.<br>";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]." 
 <br>";
    }
}
}}
?>
```

Comment: podrias poner el codigo html, del formulario, y de paso  un var_dump de $_FILES

Comment: Gracias por tu intención @ManuelAlbertoGomezLozano pero identifique el error en la linea if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i],"imagenes/".$name_array[$i]))            ya que no estaba nombrando la misma carpeta y sólo lo cambie por imagenes/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado mi problema nombrando la carpeta en la linea de código

```
 `if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "imagenes/".$name_array[$i]))`
```

Ya que el path y estas no tenían el mismo nombre.